# Difficulty in plotting Pandas Multi-indexed DataFrame or series

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, data-analysis, multi-index

[Please see this Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Luvya.png)

s = pd.DataFrame(combined_df.groupby(['session','age_range', 'gender']).size())
s.head(25)

```
​                        0
session   age_range gender        
Evening   0 - 17    female   31022
                    male     21754
          18 - 24   female   79086
                    male     71563
                    unknown     75
          25 - 29   female   29321
                    male     46125
                    unknown     44
          30 - 34   female   21480
                    male     25803
                    unknown     33
          35 - 44   female   17369
                    male     20335
                    unknown    121
          45 - 54   female    8420
                    male     12385
                    unknown     24
          55+       female    3433
                    male      9880
                    unknown    212
Mid Night 0 - 17    female   18456
                    male     12185
          18 - 24   female   50536
                    male     45829
                    unknown     62
```

This is how my Multi-indexed data Frame looks like. All I am trying to do is to plot the data in such a way that I can compare the male and female users of different age groups active during the different sessions(say Morning, Evening, Noon and  Night).
For example I will plot the Male and Female users of age group 0-17, 18-24, 25-29... during different Sessions that I have.

Note: I have tried a few examples from stack overflow and other websites still unsuccessful in getting what I need. So, I request you guys to try solving my problem and help me in finding a solution for this. I have been struggling with this for many days and even the documentation is vague. So, please throw some light on this problem.
][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BB0OJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html) with [`DataFrame.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = combined_df.groupby(['session','age_range', 'gender']).size()
df.unstack(fill_value=0).plot.bar()
plt.show()
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Thank you for the response. This solution worked for me. But the fill_value is throwing an error. So, I removed the fill_value and it worked absolutely fine. By mentioning the levels, I can go deep with the unstack method.